# How can show the following function has real roots?

Tags: calculus, polynomials

I was working on a problem and it reduced to solve the equation $f(a)=0$ where
$$f(a)=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{s}\sum_{j=1}^{r}(n-j+1)ja^jx_{ij}}{\sum_{i=1}^{s}\sum_{j=1}^{r}(n-j+1)a^jx_{ij}}-\frac{r+1}{2},~~a>0,~x_{ij}>0.$$
Has it real roots? What is your idea? Thanks.

Comment: Has it a unique real root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\sum_{i=1}^sx_{ij}=x_j$. Your function becomes
$$
f(a)=\frac{\sum_{j=1}^{r}(n-j+1)ja^jx_{j}}{\sum_{j=1}^{r}(n-j+1)a^jx_{j}}-\frac{r+1}{2}
$$
To make the computations easier let's transform our problem into investigating the existence of a positive zero of the following function
$$
g(a)=\sum_{j=1}^{r}(n-j+1)ja^jx_{j}-{r+1\over2}\sum_{j=1}^{r}(n-j+1)a^jx_{j}=\sum_{j=1}^{r}(n-j+1)x_j\left(j-{r+1\over2}\right)a^{j}
$$
which is a polynomial and thus your problem is: [polynomial root-finding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Has it a unique real root?

Comment: @K.Ahmadi If $s$ is odd it has a  real root but this root may be $0$ which is not what you want, otherwise we can't tell without knowing the coefficients.